# freopen_s on stdout causes problems with GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo on Windows

Tags: c, windows, stdout, freopen

To temporarily redirect `stdout` to a file, I'm doing:

```
printf("Before");
freopen_s(&stream, "test.txt", "w", stdout);
printf("During");
freopen_s(&stream, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
printf("After");
```

That works, however doing:

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO sbi = {0};
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &sbi);
```

No longer seems to work.  It is returning false and `GetLastError()` is returning `6` which translates into the message "The handle is invalid." with `FormatMessage`.

Any advice on why the handle might be invalid?  Interestingly, `printf` continues to work as expected and `SetConsoleTextAttribute` even works with the same handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered the following [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683171(VS.85).aspx):

> hConsoleOutput [in]
>
> > A handle to the console screen buffer. The handle must have the GENERIC_READ access right. For more information, see Console Buffer Security and Access Rights.

Thus, I would expect that adding read access to the reopen would restore the expected functionality, for example:

```
printf("Before");
freopen_s(&stream, "test.txt", "w", stdout);
printf("During");
freopen_s(&stream, "CONOUT$", "w+", stdout);
printf("After");
```